# Joomla module ordering not working

Tags: joomla

I am unable to change the order of modules in Joomla1.6. I tried by clicking the order option . But there are many modules with the same order number and it does not move up or down even after using the arrow keys.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reorder them yourself.  Type in 1,2,3,4, etc. according to the manner you want them to be in, then click the 'save' icon next to the order header.

Then refresh your page to ensure they've reorganized appropriately.

Comment: Also - I figure I should add - I don't know WHY the numbering sometimes goes silly; it just does!

Answer (score 1):

When ordering anything in Joomla, make sure the list you are looking at it ordered by the ordering column first. Most times you can not change ordering at all, unless your list is sorted by ordering first.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, and Joomla is currently 3.4.8, soon to release 3.5, and the above instructions do not apply any longer, but I thought I should add a small detail here.

In case you are working with a complex template that has many pre-installed modules at various module positions, you may come up with this:
Module ordering may not work properly if you are filtering the results in the module manager using a search keyword.

Make sure that you clear search, navigate to the position you need re-arranged (ideally, use the filters on the left column to only show that specific position) and then re-arrange. It should work.

Took me a while to realize.